# Alignment in tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

Consider the following tabular[image] with the code

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{diagbox,amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\on}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{#1}}}
    \begin{table}[h]
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
          \diagbox{b}{d}&1&2\\ \hline
          1&$-(x_{a2}x_{c2}+\on{Re}(z_{n+a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))$&\\ 
          2&$2(x_{a1}x_{c2}+\on{Im}(z_{n+a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))$&$-(x_{a1}x_{c1}+\on{Re}(z_{n+a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))$\\
          3&$-2(x_{a4}x_{c2}-\on{Re}(z_{a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))$&$2(x_{a4}x_{c1}+\on{Im}(z_a\overline{z_{n+c}}))$\\
          4&$2(x_{a3}x_{c2}-\on{Im}(z_a\overline{z_{n+c}}))$&$-2(x_{a3}x_{c1}-\on{Re}(z_a\overline{z_{n+c}}))$
        \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
      \caption{Values of $\lambda_{abcd}$ for $d\in\{1,2\}$}
      \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to align the cells to each other, so that the real and imaginary parts (as well as the signs in front of them) are aligned? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: please extend your code snippet to small but complete document which we can compile as it is.

Comment: @Zarko Sure! I hope it is okay now.

Comment: Maybe you can group the 4 rows and create a new environment, like `tabular`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suspect that you like to align real and imaginary parts of your math terms as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{diagbox,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\on}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ c|>{$}r<{$}@{\,}>{$}l<{$} | >{$}r<{$}@{\,}>{$}l<{$} }
  \diagbox{b}{d}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2}    \\ \hline
  1 & -(x_{a2}x_{c2}    & +\on{Re}(z_{n+a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))     &&  \\
  2 & 2(x_{a1}x_{c2}    & +\on{Im}(z_{n+a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))
        & -(x_{a1}x_{c1}    & +\on{Re}(z_{n+a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))  \\
  3 & -2(x_{a4}x_{c2}   & -\on{Re}(z_{a}\overline{z_{n+c}}))
        & 2(x_{a4}x_{c1}    & +\on{Im}(z_a\overline{z_{n+c}}))      \\
  4 & 2(x_{a3}x_{c2}    &  -\on{Im}(z_a\overline{z_{n+c}}))
        & -2(x_{a3}x_{c1}   & -\on{Re}(z_a\overline{z_{n+c}}))
\end{tabular}
\caption{Values of $\lambda_{abcd}$ for $d\in\{1,2\}$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the quick response! But why is the 2 in the first row not centered?

Comment: @LukeMathwalker try to modify the second `multicolumn` to this: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{2}`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked out for me. Is it better or more common to not center the second column?

Comment: @LukeMathwalker why do you say that? Because Zarko did it like that? I think he did not see that the number was misaligned, but it is not wrong to center the text; in fact, I think it's better because it helps to find the text quickly.

Comment: @manooooh Well I was only wondering whether there is a reason for the alignment. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @LukeMathwalker, oh that was error happen at copy/past of column headers ... corrected now.